# Preact - Where is render() in the default template?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, preact

The Preact tutorial makes it quite explicit that `render(App, document.body);` is required to inject the app into the DOM.

However, looking at the default template installed via preact-cli this is nowhere to be found. How does this template differ from the documented way of using Preact?

This is something I find very frustrating about documentation in general!

Comment: Not sure enough for an answer, but I'm pretty sure that `preact-cli` handles the rendering (or hydration) for you. You can see the call [here](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/blob/cb082578284bb7ebf08bfe70fefff9183dcf8013/packages/cli/lib/lib/entry.js).

Answer (score 0):

The Preact tutorial is just that, a tutorial for Preact.

Preact CLI is an entirely separate build tool. We handle rendering your app for you.